# Assign a key as key to all elements of a sibling array

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have an input JSON like this:

```
{
  "some_key": "x",
  "another_key": "y",
  "foo_id": 123,
  "all_foo": [
    {
      "foo_name": "bar1"
    },
    {
      "foo_name": "bar2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm looking for an output JSON like this:

```
{
  "some_key": "x",
  "another_key": "y",
  "all_foo": [
    {
      "foo_id": 123,
      "foo_name": "bar1"
    },
    {
      "foo_id": 123,
      "foo_name": "bar2"
    }
  ]
}
```

What I tried so far:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "all_foo": {
        "*": {
          "*": "[&1].&",
          "@(2,foo_id)": "[&1].foo_id"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

This works for `all_foo`.  But I'm unable to keep `some_key` and `another_key`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following **shift** transformation spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "some*|ano*": "&", // "some_key" or(pipe) "another_key"(* is complementary, eg. key names start with "some" or "ano")
      "all_foo": {
        "*": {
          "@2,foo_id": "&2[&1].foo_id",
          "*": "&2[&1].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where

- **`"some*|ano*": "&"`** represents replication of the outer attributes except for **`foo_id`**
- **&2**s represent going two levels up the tree, and grabbing the literal **`all_foo`** in order to form an array called **`all_foo`**